# Can someone point me in the right direction to begin parsing this string in dart?

Tags: dart, petitparser

I have a series of string like this:

```
(((S|69|L || S|69|R || S|72|L || S|72|R) && ((S|62|L && (S|78|L || S|55|L) && (S|77|L || S|1|L)) || (S|62|R && (S|78|R || S|55|R) && (S|77|R || S|1|R)))) && (M|34|L || M|34|R) && (((M|40|L && M|39|L && M|36|L) || (M|40|R && M|39|R && M|36|R)) || ((M|38|L && M|36|L && M|37|L) || (M|38|R && M|36|R && M|37|R))))
```

And I need to run items that look like `S|69|L` to see if they satisfy this criteria. You can see that it's a series of && or || operations organized by parentheses.

I'm trying to use this tutorial: https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser

But I'm having trouble getting off of the ground. Can anyone give me an example to get started with this? Maybe I just need more coffee...

Update: Making progress. This at least pulls off outside parentheses. I think I just need to continue to play with it, but I would still appreciate any tips for those who know how this works.

```
String testString = '((1||2) || 3)';

final inner = undefined();
final paren = (char('(').trim() & inner.star().flatten() & char(')').trim())
    .map((values) => values[1]);
inner.set(paren | pattern('^)'));
final parser = inner.end();
final result = parser.parse(testString);
print(result.value);
```

Comment: For me it is unclear what your goal is. What is your expected outcome when parsing your example above?

Comment: Since you seem to want a C-like syntax, have you looked at [the Dart grammar example](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser-examples/blob/main/lib/src/dart/grammar.dart) to see how it handles boolean and bitwise expressions?

Comment: @puelo At the end of the day I need to know if a list of items meets the criteria of the string. So if I have a list [S|69|R, S|62|L], it can check that against the above criteria. I think I’ll be able to achieve that if I can parse the above string into an object. I’ll admit I can’t conceptually grasp what the object will look like yet…

Comment: @jamesdin thanks yeah I was looking at that page to try and get some hints. Are you suggesting it’ll be simpler to do what I need if I use a different syntax? That’s not off the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar you provide in the question seems to work for me and the provided example inputs pass.

A couple of tips:

1. If you are not interested in the parser output, instead of calling `parser.parse(input)` you could use `parser.accept(input)` to get a boolean.
2. Similarly, if you are not interested in the output, you can drop the calls to `flatten()` and `map(...)`. Both are used to build an AST. Furthermore, `flatten()` hides the generated tree, which can make it hard to see what is happening.
3. For the actual values you could use a primitive parser like the following. However, not sure what your exact specification is?

```dart
final primitive = (uppercase() & char('|') & digit().plus() & char('|') & uppercase()).flatten().trim();
```

4. If you have the primitive parser, you can add an undefined parser for the logical expression (called `outer`) like so:

```dart
final outer = undefined();
final inner = undefined();

final operator = string('&&') | string('||');
outer.set(inner.separatedBy(operator));

final paren = char('(').trim() & outer & char(')').trim();
inner.set(paren | primitive);

final parser = outer.end();
```

5. Building expression parsers can get complicated and unwieldy quite quickly. With the Expression Builder this becomes much simpler:

```dart
final builder = ExpressionBuilder();
builder.group().primitive(primitive);
builder.group()
    .wrapper(char('(').trim(), char(')').trim(), (l, v, r) => [l, v, r]);
builder.group()
    ..left(string('&&').trim(), (a, op, b) => [a, '&&', b])
    ..left(string('||').trim(), (a, op, b) => [a, '||', b]);
final parser = builder.build().end();
```

Comment: Holy cow, the expression builder seems to have done it. Thanks! I have a lot more testing and manipulation to do, but is there a way to clean up the output a bit? For example it gives me the following List<dynamic>, but maybe this is what I need and I should work through it to get what I need.  `[(, [[(, [S|78|L, ||, S|55|L], )], &&, [(, [[(, [[M|25|L, &&, M|26|L], &&, M|27|L], )], ||, [(, [[M|5|L, &&, M|4|L], &&, M|3|L], )]], )]], )]` EDIT: I guess my biggest question is how to drop the excess layers that contain parentheses and no data. Is this simple?

Comment: EDIT 2: Now I'm understanding the logic here and I can turn it into whatever I want. This is gold, thank you.

Comment: By default PetitParser returns lists for all sequences and repetitions. You can transform the output of each parser by using [map](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/parser/MapParserExtension/map.html), or with the callbacks in the `ExpressionBuilder`. Ideally you use these callbacks to build a fully typed tree of objects. Most of the grammars in [dart-petitparser-examples](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser-examples) are typed and return a meaningful AST.